# Wrong result in sub with long long in GCC/ARM

Tags: android, c, gcc, arm, 64-bit

I have a very strange behavior with a C program for ARM(Android). I have the next code:

```
typedef long long unsigned hwtime_t;
hwtime_t hw_timer_get_hwtime (void);

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   hwtime_t m1, m2, res;  
   printf("Reading hw_timer...\n");
   m1 = hw_timer_get_hwtime();
   sleep(3);
   m2 = hw_timer_get_hwtime();
   res = m2-m1;   
   printf("Res: %llu \n",res);
   printf("Res: %llx \n",res);   
   return 0;
}
```

The function hw_timer_get_hwtime() is defined in another file:

```
hwtime_t hw_timer_get_hwtime (void) {
  struct timespec clock_time;

  linux_clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &clock_time);
  return timespec_to_ns (&clock_time);

}
```

And the timespec_to_ns is:

```
typedef long long unsigned hwtime_t;

#define NSEC_PER_SEC 1000000000L

inline hwtime_t timespec_to_ns(const struct timespec *ts)
{
    return ((hwtime_t) ts->tv_sec * NSEC_PER_SEC) + ts->tv_nsec;
}
```

The problem is that this operation: "res=m2-m1" gives a bad result several times.
For example:

```
m1= 9906000991679
m2= 9909026641585
and m2-m1 should be 3025649906 but I get 18446744072440234226
```

And few times I get the correct result. I don't know why happen this. I am compiling with arm-linux-androideabi-gcc and executing in a Nexus 5.

Comment: Could you maybe printf m1 and m2 and check these to see if this is really a calculation error or has something to do with the clock?

Comment: Try `(((hwtime_t) ts->tv_sec) * NSEC_PER_SEC)` or `#define NSEC_PER_SEC 1000000000LLU`

Comment: Try subtracting the tv_nsec and tv_sec from each other other - before converting the secs to nanosec. This way you only up scale the *difference* between the two times and not the total time

Comment: I have printed m1 and m2 and they are correct. The problem is in the substraction

Comment: I can't see any C trick here. Are you running it with an emulator? Compile it with `-S` and check the assembly.

Comment: No, I am running it with the smartphone (nexus 5)

Comment: I have checked again m1, m2 in the main program, and they are incorrect, so the problem is in the **"return ((hwtime_t) ts->tv_sec * NSEC_PER_SEC) + ts->tv_nsec;"** but if I check it in the **timespec_to_ns** function with this **"printf("Conversion seconds+ns:%lld\n", ((hwtime_t) ts->tv_sec * NSEC_PER_SEC) + ts->tv_nsec);"** I get the correct value. I am very confused

Comment: Try to confine the problem in a single unit/file, something that we can try ourselves.

Comment: The problem is in the return of the function **timespec_to_ns**, for a strange reason it doesn't return a correct 64 bits value

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, the problem was in the file that uses the function is called **timespec_to_ns** where I haven't declared the function header, so the compiler consider the return value as an integer

Comment: This is what compiler warnings are for.